# Asp.net C# Mvc3 Add database as entered value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project I have four variables in my database. FileNumber, Number, LastFileNumber and Company.

I want to create in my database as number of Number value. Like if FileNumber is 5 and Number is 3, LastFileNumber will be `5 + 3 - 1 = 7`, and it should save to database like

> FileNumber 5 Number 3 LastFileNumber 7
>
> FileNumber 6 Number 3 LastFileNumber 7
>
> FileNumber 7 Number 3 LastFileNumber 7

My code is currently:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Create(Eur1 eur1)
{
    int filenum = Convert.ToInt32(eur1.FileNumber);
    int lastfilenum = Convert.ToInt32(eur1.LastFileNumber);
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(eur1.Number);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=num;i++)
        {
            db.Eur1.AddObject(eur1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            lastfilenum = lastfilenum + 1;           
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");  
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

but of course it's saying

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `for` loop - you add the very same `eur1` object again and again. On the other hand, the assignment of `lastfilenum = lastfilenum + 1;` has no meaning, because you don't do anything with `lastfilenum`'.

Recheck your logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer; last file number has to increase by the changing of value of the number but i need to save it into database, can you help me to solve specific adding to database as an example how can i add just eur1.lastfilenumber. The think with my logic is i couldn't find how to add specif values in my model database.Because its saving all with  db.Eur1.AddObject(eur1); db.SaveChanges(); states